# How to read file JSON with json.loads

Tags: python, json

I want to get "ocr_text" in this json

How can I get ocr_text
ex:json.loads(response.text)["name"]

```html
{
    "name": "jane doe",
    "salary": 9000,
    "skills": [{
        "Raspberry pi":" MHSO",
        "Machine Learning": "MHSO",
        "Web Development": "uaskdj",
        "ocr_text": "MH 02 CB 4545"
    }],
    "email": "JaneDoe@pynative.com",
    "projects": [
        "Python Data Mining",
        "Python Data Science"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Actually it's not a properly formatted  JSON. JSON uses double quotes

Comment: [`json.loads`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.loads) reads JSON from a string.  You want to use [`json.load`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.load) to read from a file.

Comment: It just requires a series of basic dict/list item retrievals. What's the problem here?

Answer (score 0):

```
import json

jsonstr = '{ "name": "jane doe", "salary": 9000, "skills": [{ "Raspberry pi":" MHSO", "Machine Learning": "MHSO", "Web Development": "uaskdj", "ocr_text": "MH 02 CB 4545" }], "email": "JaneDoe@pynative.com", "projects": [ "Python Data Mining", "Python Data Science" ] }'
j = json.loads(jsonstr)

ocr = j["skills"][0]["ocr_text"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Paste that into the python shell and experiment

```
>>> data = {
...     "name": "jane doe",
...     "salary": 9000,
...     "skills": [{
...         "Raspberry pi":" MHSO",
...         "Machine Learning": "MHSO",
...         "Web Development": "uaskdj",
...         "ocr_text": "MH 02 CB 4545"
...     }],
...     "email": "JaneDoe@pynative.com",
...     "projects": [
...         "Python Data Mining",
...         "Python Data Science"
...     ]
... }
>>> 
>>> data["skills"]
[{'Raspberry pi': ' MHSO', 'Machine Learning': 'MHSO', 'Web Development': 'uaskdj', 'ocr_text': 'MH 02 CB 4545'}]
>>> data["skills"][0]
{'Raspberry pi': ' MHSO', 'Machine Learning': 'MHSO', 'Web Development': 'uaskdj', 'ocr_text': 'MH 02 CB 4545'}
>>> data["skills"][0]["ocr_text"]
'MH 02 CB 4545'
```

There you go. That'll get you the first ocr_text in the list. It will error if there are no items in the list. And it doesn't deal with the likelyhood that there is more than one data item in that list.